# Joomla to G Suite and Bluehost - SMTP Configuration

Tags: email, joomla, smtp, gmail, bluehost

I'm trying to Configure on Joomla the SMTP Mail Option. But try to connect via, smtp.gmail.com port 465 / smtp-relay.gmail.com port 587 with and without authentication, and with no luck.

The error I receive is a Timeout Connection error.

The Bluehost server is pointing all the Emails to G Suite.

When contacting Bluehost, they say that Google is the problem, when contacting Google they say is Bluehost that have the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following configuration to send an email via Gmail SMTP

> From Nmae - Your site email
>
> Mailer - SMTP
>
> SMTP Host - smtp.gmail.com
>
> SMTP Port - 465
>
> SMTP Security - SSL/TLS
>
> SMTP Authentication - Yes

If you have enabled the 2 factor authentication for your profile then you need to follow more steps as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26736062/sending-email-fails-when-two-factor-authentication-is-on-for-gmail)

Comment: I try, with no luck!