# send email in laravel by gmail smtp server

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, gmail

I want to use Gmail to send emails through Laravel.
When I apply through localhost, the email is sent correctly.
But it gives the following error on the server and the email is not sent.

```
local.ERROR: Swift_TransportException: Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com $:stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to tcp://smtp.gmail.com:587 (Connection timed out)
```

Comment: try to change `MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl` to `MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls`

Comment: I did this with both tls, but in both cases the same error returned

Comment: Have you allowed access for "Less Secure Apps" in your Gmail settings?

Comment: Yes, I made Gmail security settings

Answer (score 1):

Hello I had the same problem probably your solution is like that, because this helps me to resolved my issue

Create a custom app in you Gmail security settings.

1. Log-in into Gmail with your account
2. Navigate to https://security.google.com/settings/security/apppasswords
3. In 'select app' choose 'custom', give it an arbitrary name and press generate
4. It will give you 16 chars token.`
   Use the token as password in combination with your full Gmail account and two factor authentication will not be required.

Note: The link in step 2 will work only if you have 2-factor-authentication enabled.

For Refference: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26736062/sending-email-fails-when-two-factor-authentication-is-on-for-gmail)

Comment: The setting you are looking for is not available for your account.

Answer (score 0):

**use mail trap for testing**

**`link` `https://mailtrap.io/` where you get your all smtp credential and put in `.env` file**

Comment: thanks.
It was a really good website.
My application is working properly and the email was received in mailtrap.
There is definitely a problem connecting to Gmail while the Gmail security settings are in place.
But the question is, where is the problem?

Comment: Could it be a problem with my server server?
I bought the server from Hetzner Online AG in Germany.
Could the IP range of this server be limited by Google?

Comment: might be your credentials issue, check your credentials

Comment: Authentication information is correct.
The server's suffering is probably blacklisted.